# SAX Parser having parent and child tags similar

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am using SAX parser to parse XML which has parent and its children tags something like this:

```
<A Name="Parent"  level="0">
    <A Name="Child" level="0">
        <A Name="SubChild01" level="1">
            <A Name="SubChild11" level="1">
            </A>
        </A>
        <A Name="SubChild11" level="1">
        </A>
    </A>
    <A Name="Child2" level="0">
        <A Name="SubChild02" level="1">
        </A>
    </A>
</A>
```

Code

```
Class Node{
    List<Integer> childNodeId=new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

To save `childnodes` id to its immediate subsequent parent. 
How this can be achieved?

Comment: please post full java code.

Comment: also you can't have comma in xml ...

Comment: <A Name="Child2",level="0"> to <A Name="Child2" level="0">

Comment: You have to build a tree!

Answer (score 2):

With the vast majority of SAX applications, you have to maintain a stack. You push information onto the stack when you are notified of StartElement, and you pop the stack on EndElement events. You can find the information relevant to the parent of the current element by a peek() at the top of the stack.